# How can I use a webpage with python?

Tags: python, html, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new to python, and I want to access a webpage in which to log in I have to type my username first, click a button. Then, type the password and click another button. But I'm struggling with that.

So far Python lets me open the webpage and type my username and click the first button. But the page loads for the password, it doesn't happens anything, no typing nor nothing.

I'm using

```
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pass"]')
    password.send_keys(configBur.PASSWORD)
```

But I also used `passowrd = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")`, also nothing happened. IS there something missing with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the webdriver wait feature, maybe the page doesn't load the element before you try to access it.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'pass')))
password.send_keys(configBur.PASSWORD)
```

Alternatively try using `time.sleep`

```
import time

time.sleep(10)
password = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
password.send_keys(configBur.PASSWORD)
```